# textbox doesn't disable on select change in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have actually two problems.

Problem 1:

When I select the option which has value `all` then input with text should disable otherwise it should not be disabled here is my codee..

```
<input type="text" name="store" class="form-control" value="{{$search}}" placeholder="Enter Store name, email or username. Don't forget to pick respective filter" id="store-text" />
<select class="form-control" name="filter" id="search-filters" required>
        <option value="all">All Stores</option>
        <option value="name">By Name</option>
        <option value="email">By Email</option>
        <option value="username">By Username</option>
      </select>
```

And jquery part:

```
$("#search-filters").change(function()
{
var filter_val = this.val();
if(filter_val == "all")
{
  $("#store-text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
else
{
  $("#store-text").removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

This is not working neither there are any errors in console.

Problem 2:

I am getting the parameter value from url lets say `www.abc.com?filter=all`
whatever is the filter value it should filter its respective option in select box and mark it `selected`

```
var filter = getParameter('filter');
 if(filter != "")
 {
    $("#store-text").find('option[value='+filter+']').attr('selected');
 }
```

I am getting parameter but my code isn't selecting the option.

I am using `jquery.min-3.1.1.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Problem 1*

You have missed to wrap `this` with the `$`. Doing so you would have access to the `val` function, which is a function of a jQuery object. Otherwise you cannot access any method, because it is not defined on this.

```js
$(function(){

  $("#search-filters").change(function(){
    var filter_val = $(this).val();
    if(filter_val == "all"){
      $("#store-text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else{
      $("#store-text").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="store" class="form-control" value="{{$search}}" placeholder="Enter Store name, email or username. Don't forget to pick respective filter" id="store-text" />
<select class="form-control" name="filter" id="search-filters" required>
        <option value="all">All Stores</option>
        <option value="name">By Name</option>
        <option value="email">By Email</option>
        <option value="username">By Username</option>
      </select>
```

*Problem2*

If you want to set the selected value of your select list option you could try this:

```
$("#search-filters").val(filter).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking! :)

Answer (score 0):

*Problem 1:*

You need to create a jQuery object to use jQuery methods i.e. [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) should be used to get/set the properties.

```
$("#search-filters").change(function() {
    $("#store-text").prop("disabled", $(this).val() == 'all');
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#search-filters").change(function() {
    $("#store-text").prop("disabled", $(this).val() == 'all');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Store name, email or username. Don't forget to pick respective filter" id="store-text" />
<select class="form-control" name="filter" id="search-filters" required>
  <option value="all">All Stores</option>
  <option value="name">By Name</option>
  <option value="email">By Email</option>
  <option value="username">By Username</option>
</select>
```

*Problem 2:*

`store-text` is an *input* element it doesn't have `option` child elements. I think you intend to set the `select` elements value so use correct selector and just use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set the selected option and use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event handler to set the `disabled` state of `input`

```
$("#search-filters").val(filter).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this)` instead of `this`.And Initiate the function at the time of `document.load` .It will check the option value.

```js
$("#search-filters").change(function () {
  var filter_val = $(this).val();
  if (filter_val == "all") {
    $("#store-text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
    $("#store-text").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
$("#search-filters").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="store" class="form-control" value="{{$search}}" placeholder="Enter Store name, email or username. Don't forget to pick respective filter" id="store-text" />
<select class="form-control" name="filter" id="search-filters" required>
  <option value="all">All Stores</option>
  <option value="name">By Name</option>
  <option value="email">By Email</option>
  <option value="username">By Username</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

```
$("#search-filters").change(function() {
  var filter_val = this.value;
  if (filter_val == "all") {
    $("#store-text").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#store-text").attr("disabled", false);
  }
}).change();
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/1wusmusL/1/

For problem 2:
Set selected value using

```
$("#search-filters").val(filter);
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/1wusmusL/2/

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM 1 SOLUTION:**
I think  you are not binding the change event in **$(document).ready** so you are not getting the click event hooked up with the select change.Your code is good.but doing this will solve your prob I hope. Refer this link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/buhudzBJNBYZGe8LUQHN?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search-filters').on('change', function() { 
    if(this.value == 'all'){
      $("#store-text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }else{
        $("#store-text").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  }); 
});
```

**PROBLEM 2 SOLUTION:**

```
 $("#store-text").val("YOUR VALUE");
```

HOPE IT HELPS!!